# Display Main App View Controller as Custom Layout of Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I want to add a share extension to my project. I need to show my app's contact list page when the user shares things using my app's extension - just like WhatsApp does.

I want to use my main app container's contact list page.

When I add the class, the share extension won't work and an error appears.

What i did

I have just add extension which create the `shareViewController` programmatically.

I have change the `ShareViewController` from `SLServiceVC` to `UIViewController` and comment all the method of it.

After, I added the following code:

```
ContactsViewController *vc = [[ContactsViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ContactsViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

When I do this I get this error:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ContactsViewController", referenced from:

Comment: Share what you've tried so far (code), and which errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for help : I have just add extention which create the shareViewController programatically

I have change the ShareViewController from SLServiceVC to UIViewController and comment all the method of it

After i added following code

 ContactsViewController *vc = [[ContactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

when i do this i get error

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ContactsViewController", referenced from:

Comment: You should update your question with all the content you just posted as comment. That makes it easier for everyone to follow.

Comment: ok sure thanks, but do you have any idea how to get rid of it ?

Comment: That error message does not seem complete. Does it say anything else?

Comment: add ContactsViewController to the Extension's Target

Comment: @LinusGeffarth : Just Linker command error : symbol not found for architecture x_86_64

Comment: add ContactsViewController to the Extension's Target – Ragul :

@Ragul you meant that i need to add ContactsViewController in extention target - buildphase- compile sources ?

Comment: select target membership for ContactsViewController in both your App and its extension

Comment: i did but when  i add contactViewController in target membership its give so many error like :

shareApplication is unavailable  not available on IOS extension - Use view controller base solution